# server error occurred | how to send email with pdf attachments via google script in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to send emails with pdf attachment wia Google script.
 
But faced with  error "server error occurred" and I can't understand the reason of this error.

Full script takes arguments from Google Sheet Table and has to send email.

```js
function onEdit(e) 
{   
  var responceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = responceSheet.getLastRow();
  var namesRange = responceSheet.getRange(rows, 3, 1, 1);
  var emailsRange = responceSheet.getRange(rows, 1, 1, 1);
  var nameSender = namesRange.getValue();
  var emailSender = emailsRange.getValue();

  var emailReplyTo = "2teachingsecrets@gmail.com";
  var subject = "subject example";
  var body = "test body";

// Send an email with  attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) 
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Google Drive file ID');

MailApp.sendEmail(emailSender, subject, body,  {attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
 }
```

Script with MailApp.sendEmail function **without attachment option** is working well.

If I add

> {attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]}

or just

> {attachments:[file]}

I receive

> "Sorry, a server error occurred. Please try again later."

Solution which were reviewed: [google script email range as pdf attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413155/google-script-email-range-as-pdf-attachment) but it does not help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `catch`ing the error and logging to see if that gets you some more info: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging